# Vlookup macro keep popping up file explorer when populating the rest of the column

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub vlooupReclass()
 With ActiveSheet
    .Range("A1").AutoFilter 4, "0"
    .AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).Columns(4).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-3],[a]pivotable!R400000C3:R2C4,2,False)"
    .Range("D2:D" & Cells(Rows.count, "D").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells (xlCellTypeVisible)
    .Range("D" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).ClearContents
    .AutoFilterMode = False

    End With
     With ActiveSheet
    .Range("A1").AutoFilter 5, "0"
    .AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).Columns(5).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-4],[a]pivotable!R400000C3:R2C4,2,False)"
    .Range("E2:E" & Cells(Rows.count, "E").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells (xlCellTypeVisible)
    .Range("E" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).ClearContents
    .AutoFilterMode = False

    End With
     With ActiveSheet
    .Range("A1").AutoFilter 6, "0"
    .AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).Columns(6).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-5],[a]pivotable!R400000C3:R2C4,2,False)"
    .Range("F2:F" & Cells(Rows.count, "F").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells (xlCellTypeVisible)
    .Range("F" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).ClearContents
    .AutoFilterMode = False

    End With
    End Sub
```

This code works as i want it to work only issue is after it does the first column(column "D") it continues to open file explore over and over and doesn't move on to the next column in this case it doesn't move on to column E it gets stuck opening a ton of files explores. Is there a particular reason that its doing that and is there any way to get around it?

Comment: Do you have any other macros running, especially something like a `Worksheet_Change`?

Comment: No I usually just run one macro at a time. When i tried to do ctrl+D on the column i also got a bunch of file explores popping up and this was after the macro was fished running .

Comment: i believe the problem is not in your macro, its in your data, there is some problematic formula in you sheets that is showing the popup.

Comment: It only happen when I use the Vlookup macro. Im not using any other formulas in my sheet. It only happen when the Vlookup formula populates the rest of the cells

Comment: @PeterT i figured out what the issue is. In this formula =VLOOKUP(RC[-5],[a]pivotable!R400000C3:R2C4,2,False) I use "a" and because its not an actual file name it pop up file explore for me to choose and if i try to populate that formula into other cells, it pops file explore open.  I havent figured out a solution i have hoping to get some help in that are.

Comment: @usmanhaq i explained the issue above please let me know if you have any input

Comment: What is `[a]` supposed to be if it's not a real file name? Are you expecting a substitution or something?

Comment: Copy the data from the file you are referring as [a] to your macro file in a separate sheet, than reference that sheet in your formula. for example if you copy the pivot data in Sheet1; your formula will become Sheet1!R400000C3:R2C4